# Updating DataFrame Value

Tags: python, pandas

With this DataFrame called `data`...

```
                    winner
 runner_name                         
 Steve                   0
 Joe                     0
 Marsha                  1
 Kent                    0
```

if I create a new column with a placeholder of 0...

```
 data['weighted'] = 0
```

When I pass a decimal value to update it in a loop (after a long series of calculations and other stuff)...

```
 data.ix[runner_name]['weighted'] = 45.88
```

...it automatically rounds the figure. Thus, the frame becomes..

```
                    winner  weighted
 runner_name                         
 Steve                   0        46
 Joe                     0        80
 Marsha                  1       100
 Kent                    0        80
```

How do I prevent it from rounding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a float will cause Pandas to give the column a `float` dtype:

```
data['weighted'] = 0.0
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'winner':[0,0,1,0]}, index=pd.Series(['Steve', 'Joe', 'Marsha', 'Kent'], name='runner_name'), )
data['weighted'] = 0.0
data.ix['Steve', 'weighted'] = 45.88
print(data)
```

yields

```
             winner  weighted
runner_name                  
Steve             0     45.88
Joe               0      0.00
Marsha            1      0.00
Kent              0      0.00
```

---

```
>>> print(data.dtypes)
winner        int64
weighted    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: It's still rounding. Even if I manually adjust it such as `data.ix[runner_name, 'weighted'] = 3.14` ... it still rounds it (to 3 in this case).

Comment: That was it. I needed to assign it a float to begin with. Thank you!